# varnish and real ip address, how?

Tags: apache, nginx, ip, varnish

I used nginx in front and apache for backend, also varnish for caching

now, IP of all of the visitors return as 127.0.0.1

How can I config my server to return real ip of customers?

I did test many ways but none of them correct and work for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem solved!

Just change nginx config!

open

```
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

And add the following lines to your http{} statement

```
set_real_ip_from   127.0.0.1;
real_ip_header     X-Forwarded-For;
```

Comment: Do you by any chance have a fix for Varnish + Apache? It keeps logging Cloudflare IPs instead of real IPs in access log.